# How make simple slick insert with Lifted query and Option columns

Tags: scala, insert, slick

I can't seem to understand how to make a simple insert into a Database using Slick. I'm using tables generator with my Oracle db and I'm getting something like this:

```
 case class SimulatonRow(id: scala.math.BigDecimal, startDate: Option[java.sql.Timestamp], endDate: Option[java.sql.Timestamp], numberOfProc: Option[scala.math.BigDecimal], code: String)
  /** GetResult implicit for fetching SimulatonRow objects using plain SQL queries */
  implicit def GetResultSimulatonRow(implicit e0: GR[scala.math.BigDecimal], e1:     GR[Option[java.sql.Timestamp]], e2: GR[Option[scala.math.BigDecimal]], e3: GR[String]): GR[SimulatonRow] = GR{
prs => import prs._
SimulatonRow.tupled((<<[scala.math.BigDecimal], <<?[java.sql.Timestamp], <<?[java.sql.Timestamp], <<?[scala.math.BigDecimal], <<[String]))
  }
 class Simulaton(tag: Tag) extends Table[SimulatonRow](tag, Some("BPRISK"), "SIMULATON") {
def * = (id, startDate, endDate, numberOfProc, code) <> (SimulatonRow.tupled, SimulatonRow.unapply)
/** Maps whole row to an option. Useful for outer joins. */
def ? = (id.?, startDate, endDate, numberOfProc, code.?).shaped.<>({r=>import r._; _1.map(_=> SimulatonRow.tupled((_1.get, _2, _3, _4, _5.get)))}, (_:Any) =>  throw new Exception("Inserting into ? projection not supported."))

/** Database column ID PrimaryKey */
val id: Column[scala.math.BigDecimal] = column[scala.math.BigDecimal]("ID", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
/** Database column START_DATE  */
val startDate: Column[Option[java.sql.Timestamp]] = column[Option[java.sql.Timestamp]]("START_DATE")
/** Database column END_DATE  */
val endDate: Column[Option[java.sql.Timestamp]] = column[Option[java.sql.Timestamp]]("END_DATE")
/** Database column NUMBER_OF_PROC  */
val numberOfProc: Column[Option[scala.math.BigDecimal]] = column[Option[scala.math.BigDecimal]]("NUMBER_OF_PROC")
/** Database column CODE  */
val code: Column[String] = column[String]("CODE")
  }
```

Then I add AutoInc option to the primary key.

I tried variations of 'insert' with TableQuery[Simulaton].map or InsertInvoker, but the code cannot be compiled.

How does it work?

I need to make an 'insert' with autoincremental PK and columns - code, startDate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// import driver specific stuff
import MySQLDriver.simple._

// import generated code
import Tables._

// define db connection
val db = Database.for...

// create a connection
db.withSession{ implicit session =>

    // select what should be inserted into
    TableQuery[Simulaton].map(s => (s.code,s.startDate))
                         // insert instead or running the query
                         .insert( ("some code",Some(DateTime.now)) )

}
```

Comment: overloaded method value insert with alternatives:
[error]   [TT](query: scala.slick.lifted.Query[TT,(String, Option[java.sql.Timestamp])])(implicit session: scala.slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend#SessionDef)Int <and>
[error]   (value: (String, Option[java.sql.Timestamp]))(implicit session: scala.slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend#SessionDef)Int
[error]  cannot be applied to ((String, java.sql.Timestamp))
[error]             .insert( (processId,now ))
[error]              ^

Comment: I think 'id' column must be braced in Option[] to be ignored in insert statement, but i can't understand, how to change model

Comment: Fixed a missing `Some` in the answer. Type errors can be a bit scary with Slick, when something fails. Check that types and Options match if you get some. Inline type ascriptions can help as well.

Comment: I change model and code like next was compiled. TableQuery[Simulaton].map(s => s)+= SimulatonRow(id=None,code=processId,startDate=Option(now),numberOfProc=None,endDate=None )
          Now i solve other problem and cannot check that variant.

Comment: Your variant also compiled, and seemed more likely for me. Thanks! But now i have Exception [info] [ERROR] [05/19/2014 23:23:04.130] [bprisk-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] [akka://bprisk/user/runner] ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("BPRISK"."SIMULATON"."ID")
[info] 
[info] java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("BPRISK"."SIMULATON"."ID")  and may think that autoincrement not works with oracle

Comment: AutoInc columns should be automatically ignore in inserts. Please file a bug with reproduce code in the Slick github project.